# using bluebird with undefined success callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, memcached, bluebird

I am using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) library over [memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/memcached).

```
memcached.set('foo', 'bar', 10, function (err) { /* stuff */ });
```

this function does not call success callback in second parameter so seems like .then(res) function does not getting called.

```
 Promise.promisifyAll(memcached);
 memcached.setAsync(hashedCacheKey, obj).then(function (res) {
            resolve(res);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            reject(err, null);
        });
```

is there any way for me to handle uncalled success event?

Comment: @raina77ow it is getting generated after "Promise.promisifyAll(memcached);" I edited my post.

Comment: Sidenote, it looks like you might be unnecessarily wrapping your logic in a `new Promise` constructor.

Comment: @Retsam I am returning new promise since calling function is using then/catch signature as well.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi  It sounds like you're using the Promise constructor antipattern.  You really should just return `memcached.setAsync`'s promise directly.   See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: @Retsam two answers in one question! Thanks for pointing that out, I changed the way you suggested and much more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: @Teomanshipahi No problem, glad it's working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary issue here is that you're not providing a timeout argument to `memcached.setAsync`, but it's a mandatory argument for `memcached.set`.  These two lines are equivalent:

```
memcached.set("foo", "bar", () => { /* this is never called */ });
memcached.setAsync("foo", "bar").then(() => { /* this is never called, either */ })
```

Add a timeout argument and your code should work as expected.